# Convert C# code to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL Server stored procedures.

I want to convert this C# code into a SQL Server stored procedure.

```
int i = 0;

While(i >= 0)
{
    int count = checkvalue(name); // function checkvalue return integer value. & name is string value like "rest-123".

    if(count == 0)
    {
          -- insert query in which name is inserted to some table.
          break;
    }

    i++;

    string Tempname = string.Format("{0}-{1}", name, i); // This write string like "rest-123-1"
    name = Tempname
}
```

I want to know

1. How to break while loop after if condition is true & record is inserted.
2. How to perform this `string Tempname = string.Format("{0}-{1}", name, i);` operation in T-SQL stored procedure

Please guide me or provide me reference to write this stored procedure.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: **Why on earth** would you want to do this?? T-SQL is **NOT** ideally suited for things like looping and string manipulations - those are **better** handled in C# .....

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the commenters that this is a terrible idea, and you have no attempt at code posted. So here are generic examples.

That said:
[Looping and BREAK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190385(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
WHILE (SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) < $300
BEGIN
   UPDATE Production.Product
      SET ListPrice = ListPrice * 2
   SELECT MAX(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product
   IF (SELECT MAX(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) > $500
      BREAK
   ELSE
      CONTINUE
END
PRINT 'Too much for the market to bear';
```

[String contatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx): (example is sql columns but variables work the same, with a plus sign. Watch for NULL, if DB setting is turned on, string concat of null yields null)

```
SELECT (LastName + ', ' + FirstName) AS Name
FROM Person.Person
ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName ASC;
```